# primary key column were entried duplicately when load data from user file

Tags: oracle

Oracle 11g

step 1.

```
create table pur_order(
               po_number number primary key,
               po_date date,
               po_vendor number,
                :)
```

step 2.load data with Enterprise Manager 11g from a user file podata.txt content like:

```
  1 25-JUN-2011 1001
  2 26-JUN-2011 1002
  3 27-JUN-2011 1003
  1 27-JUN-2011 1001
  2 28-JUN-2011 1002
```

step 3. the loading process finished successfully.

table content is just like above
problem is as I have already defined po_number as primary key,why duplicate values of po_number still be able to be loaded?

Comment: How did you do the loading? imp/exp, sqlloader or other?

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the contents of "select pur_order, count(*) from pur_order group by pur_order" after the load? What is the delimiter for this file? (how are the fields being seperated?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely this method of import uses the SQL*Loader utility with the Direct Path Load method. This disables some integrity constraints as explained in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch09.htm#1007642):

> Integrity constraints that depend on other rows or tables, such as referential constraints, are disabled before the direct path load and must be reenabled afterwards. If REENABLE is specified, SQL*Loader can reenable them automatically at the end of the load. When the constraints are reenabled, the entire table is checked. Any rows that fail this check are reported in the specified error log. See [Direct Loads, Integrity Constraints, and Triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch09.htm#1008082).

SQL*Loader tried to reenable the constraint but failed and thus:

> The index will be left in an Index Unusable state if a violation of a UNIQUE constraint is detected. See [Indexes Left in an Unusable State](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch09.htm#1007759).

I'm pretty sure you will find that the primary key index is unusable (`SELECT index_name, status FROM all_indexes WHERE table_name = 'PUR_ORDER'`).

Either load the datafile without direct path load or make sure that the constraint is successfully enabled afterwards.